# How to properly implement a radio button section in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, radio-button, sections

Hello I am new to react native and I have a problem I am trying to create my component option which will have several sections with radio buttons. As on a delivery application where you choose, for example, the ordering options for a menu. I was able to create the radio buttons with the data that I declared in constant only the problem is that I am not able to ensure that we can check a value in each section. which means that with all the sections I can only check one value. and that's not really what I want. I put my code below. i would like to retrieve the selected value in each section and store it in a variable an array will be great and i dont know how to go about it.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
 
const products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Soft Drinks',
    data: [
      {
        label: 'Coca Cola',
        price: '500 KMF',
      },
      {
        label: 'Fanta',
        price: '250 KMF',
      },
      {
        label: 'Sprite',
        price: '200 KMF',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Juices',
    data: [
      {
        label: 'Mango',
        price: '500 KMF',
      },
      {
        label: 'Orange',
        price: '250 KMF',
      },
      {
        label: 'Strawberry',
        price: '200 KMF',
      },
    ],
  },
];
 
class RadioButton extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedValue: [],
    };
  }
 
  radioClick(label) {
    this.setState({
      selectedValue: [label]
    })
  }
 
  render() {
 
    console.log(this.state.selectedValue)
 
    return (
      <View>
        {products.map((object, d) => (
          <View key={products.id} style={styles.sectionContainer}>
            <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>{object.title}</Text>
            {object.data.map((item, i) => (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={item.label}
                  onPress={this.radioClick.bind(this, item.label)}
                  style={styles.radio}>
                  <View style={styles.radioContainer}>
                    {item.label == this.state.selectedValue ? (
                      <View style={styles.activeButton} />
                    ) : null}
                  </View>
                  <Text style={styles.label}>{item.label}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.price}>+ {item.price}</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            ))}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  sectionContainer: {
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    paddingVertical: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)',
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    letterSpacing: 2,
    fontWeight: '500',
    color: '#737372',
    fontSize: 14,
  },
  radio: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
    paddingVertical: 12,
    alignItems: 'center',
    position: 'relative',
  },
  radioContainer: {
    height: 20,
    width: 20,
    borderRadius: 12,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  activeButton: {
    height: 12,
    width: 12,
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
  },
  label: {
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '500',
    letterSpacing: 1.5,
  },
  price: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '500',
    letterSpacing: 1.5,
    textAlign: 'right',
    color: '#737372',
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 15,
  },
});
 
export default RadioButton;
```

[Radio Button Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oEzj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the component RadioButton from react-native-paper

First, don't forget to import React Native Paper to your code:

```
import { RadioButton, Text } from 'react-native-paper';
```

Then you can easily create Radio Groups like this:

```
<RadioButton.Group onValueChange={newValue => setValue(newValue)} value={value}>
    <View>
        <Text>First</Text>
        <RadioButton value="first" />
    </View>
    <View>
        <Text>Second</Text>
        <RadioButton value="second" />
    </View>
</RadioButton.Group>
```

See more details on the documentation: https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button.html